# yith wishlist pluggin - header icon change color when have items in wishlist

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

so im using YITH Wishlist plugin (pro)
i found that they have a shortcode to display the amount of products in the Wishlist using php

```
if ( defined( 'YITH_WCWL' ) && ! function_exists( 
'yith_wcwl_get_items_count' ) ) {
  function yith_wcwl_get_items_count() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url() ); ?>">
    <span class="yith-wcwl-items-count">
      <i class="yith-wcwl-icon fa fa-heart-o"><?php echo esc_html( 
yith_wcwl_count_all_products() ); ?></i>
    </span>
  </a>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
  }

  add_shortcode( 'yith_wcwl_items_count', 'yith_wcwl_get_items_count' );
}

    if ( defined( 'YITH_WCWL' ) && ! function_exists( 
'yith_wcwl_ajax_update_count' ) ) {
  function yith_wcwl_ajax_update_count() {
   wp_send_json( array(
  'count' => yith_wcwl_count_all_products()
   ) );
  }

  add_action( 'wp_ajax_yith_wcwl_update_wishlist_count', 
'yith_wcwl_ajax_update_count' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_yith_wcwl_update_wishlist_count', 
'yith_wcwl_ajax_update_count' );
}

if ( defined( 'YITH_WCWL' ) && ! function_exists( 
'yith_wcwl_enqueue_custom_script' ) ) {
  function yith_wcwl_enqueue_custom_script() {
    wp_add_inline_script(
      'jquery-yith-wcwl',
      "
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
      $( document ).on( 'added_to_wishlist removed_from_wishlist', 
function() {
        $.get( yith_wcwl_l10n.ajax_url, {
          action: 'yith_wcwl_update_wishlist_count'
        }, function( data ) {
          $('.yith-wcwl-items-count').children('i').html( data.count );
        } );
      } );
    } );
      "
    );
      }

      add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 
'yith_wcwl_enqueue_custom_script', 20 );
    }
```

the thing is, i dont want it to count the amount of products in the Wishlist.
i only want the icon color to change to "red" when the Wishlist contains products =>1

how can i adjust the current code to do so?

i attached below the original code from their website

this is a simple wordpress + woocommerce website. the shortcode does work perfectly for what its set to do, i simply want it to change the color of the icon when there are products in the wishlist instead of counting how many products

Answer (score 0):

In your shortcode remove the `yith_wcwl_count_all_products()` function since you dont want show it. Then we need to change the js script to add class if we have items in our wishlist or remove it.

Full code

In the js part edit `$('.yith-wcwl-icon').addClass('red');` and `$('.yith-wcwl-icon').removeClass('red');` to class you want to use.

```
if ( defined( 'YITH_WCWL' ) && ! function_exists( 'yith_wcwl_get_items_count' ) ) {
    function yith_wcwl_get_items_count() {
      ob_start();
      ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url() ); ?>">
          <span class="yith-wcwl-items-count">
            <i class="yith-wcwl-icon fa fa-heart-o"></i>
          </span>
        </a>
      <?php
      return ob_get_clean();
    }
  
    add_shortcode( 'yith_wcwl_items_count', 'yith_wcwl_get_items_count' );
  }
  
  if ( defined( 'YITH_WCWL' ) && ! function_exists( 'yith_wcwl_ajax_update_count' ) ) {
    function yith_wcwl_ajax_update_count() {
      wp_send_json( array(
        'count' => yith_wcwl_count_all_products()
      ) );
    }
  
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_yith_wcwl_update_wishlist_count', 'yith_wcwl_ajax_update_count' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_yith_wcwl_update_wishlist_count', 'yith_wcwl_ajax_update_count' );
  }
  
  if ( defined( 'YITH_WCWL' ) && ! function_exists( 'yith_wcwl_enqueue_custom_script' ) ) {
    function yith_wcwl_enqueue_custom_script() {
      wp_add_inline_script(
        'jquery-yith-wcwl',
        "
          jQuery( function( $ ) {
            $( document ).on( 'added_to_wishlist removed_from_wishlist', function() {
              $.get( yith_wcwl_l10n.ajax_url, {
                action: 'yith_wcwl_update_wishlist_count'
              }, function( data ) {
                if(data.count > 0) {
                    //replace red with class you prefer
                    $('.yith-wcwl-icon').addClass('red');
                } else {
                    //if you change the class you add update the class you remove too
                    $('.yith-wcwl-icon').removeClass('red');
                }
              } );
            } );
          } );
        "
      );
    }
  
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yith_wcwl_enqueue_custom_script', 20 );
  }
```

Comment: that seem great however, when i inserted the full code it doesn't seem to work. i added to the frontend the shortcode: [yith_wcwl_items_count]  and great it doesn't count products anymore but it doesn't turn red when products in Wishlist either. can you assist me with a fully copy>paste code please :) <3 and thanks alot for the help!

Comment: Do you see if the class is added or not ? Do you get any errors in your console? You need to add in your css style too to change the color if you didnt something like that should be fine `i.yith-wcwl-icon.fa.fa-heart-o.red { color: red; }` . I tested one more time the code and its working fine.

Comment: I see its adding the class. So what you need to do is to add this css line in your child theme `i.yith-wcwl-icon.fa.fa-heart-o.red { color: red; }`